# swift: reload view for displaying new data in chart

Tags: ios, swift, view, charts, reload

im using the chart-framework 'Charts', however it has no reload function for the chart with new data. It can only display the chart once with loading the viewController. But i want to reload the view/chart with a selection from a table. (the table is in other viewcontroller)

in my case, i have a ViewController with a view inside
and data are in two arrays: x and y

```
func setChartData(x: [Double], y: [Double])
```

I tried to call the function but it doesnt display it.
If the function is called from viewWillAppear()
the chart is only showing, if i switch to another viewcontroller and switch back

how can i solve this

self.view!.setNeedsDisplay() within the function is not working.

My viewcontroller:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    setChartData(resultID_statistics, y: resultWeight_statistics)

}

func setChartData(x: [Double], y: [Double])  {

    // 1 - creating an array of data entries
    var yVals1 : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
    for var i = 0; i < x.count; i++ {
        yVals1.append(ChartDataEntry(value: y[i], xIndex: i))
    }

    // 2 - create a data set with our array
    let set1: LineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(yVals: yVals1, label: "First Set")
    set1.axisDependency = .Left // Line will correlate with left axis values
    set1.setColor(UIColor.redColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)) // our line's opacity is 50%
    set1.setCircleColor(UIColor.redColor()) // our circle will be dark red
    set1.lineWidth = 2.0
    set1.circleRadius = 6.0 // the radius of the node circle
    set1.fillAlpha = 65 / 255.0
    set1.fillColor = UIColor.redColor()
    set1.highlightColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    set1.drawCircleHoleEnabled = true

    //3 - create an array to store our LineChartDataSets
    var dataSets : [LineChartDataSet] = [LineChartDataSet]()
    dataSets.append(set1)

    //4 - pass our months in for our x-axis label value along with our dataSets
    let data: LineChartData = LineChartData(xVals: x, dataSets: dataSets)
    data.setValueTextColor(UIColor.whiteColor())

    //5 - finally set our data
    self.lineChartView.data = data

    data.notifyDataChanged()
    lineChartView.notifyDataSetChanged()

}
```

Comment: I tried to add the values into global arrays, and call the function from viewWillAppear     override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        setChartData(resultID_statistics, y: resultWeight_statistics)
    }

Comment: it doesn't reload when calling from viewwillappear?

Comment: no it doesnt, only if i switch to other VC and switch back

Answer (score 11):

From their documentation is seems that you need to notify the change in data sets:

```
 // EXAMPLE 1
 // add entries to the "data" object
 exampleData.addEntry(...);
 chart.notifyDataSetChanged(); // let the chart know it's data changed
 chart.invalidate(); // refresh

 // EXAMPLE 2
 // add entries to "dataSet" object
 dataSet.addEntry(...);
 exampleData.notifyDataChanged(); // let the data know a dataSet changed
 chart.notifyDataSetChanged(); // let the chart know it's data changed
 chart.invalidate(); // refresh
```

For more information check out their [wiki](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Dynamic-&-Realtime-Data).

---

*note: from repo README:*

> Currently there's no need for documentation for the iOS/tvOS/OSX
>   version, as the API is 95% the same as on Android. You can read the official MPAndroidChart documentation here: Wiki

*so when you click the link and see "MPAndroidChart" don't be alarmed :)*

---

You can also try:

```
chart.data.notifyDataChanged()
chart.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

This is taken from their example project in objective-c:

```
  LineChartDataSet *set1 = nil;
    if (_chartView.data.dataSetCount > 0)
    {
        set1 = (LineChartDataSet *)_chartView.data.dataSets[0];
        set1.values = values;
        [_chartView.data notifyDataChanged];
        [_chartView notifyDataSetChanged];
    }
```

Comment: i cant call the function invalidate(), because not exists?
i tried this functions without results:
        lineChartView.notifyDataSetChanged()
        lineChartView.setNeedsDisplay()

Comment: thank you for the try, but the chart is not updating with chart.data.notifyDataChanged()
chart.notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: @mostworld77 can you post more of your code implementation

Comment: `self.lineChartView.data.notifyDataChanged() ` along with `self.lineChartView.notifyDataChanged() ` didn't work correct?

Comment: the method: `self.lineChartView.notifyDataChanged()` dont exists, do you mean `self.lineChartView.notifyDataSetChanged()` ? also dont work

Comment: @mostworld77 correct. Do you have access to that method for `self.lineChartView.data`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122213/discussion-between-mostworld77-and-random).